# Move a std::string to function param

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I'd like to move a large std::string to a member of class.

And this is my code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
public:
    void some_method(std::string&& str) {
        my_str = str;
    }

    std::string my_str;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass some_class;

    std::string large_str(100000, 'a');

    some_class.some_method(std::move(large_str));

    assert(large_str.empty());
    assert(!some_class.my_str.empty());
    return 0;
}
```

When after move, i expect the `large_str` is empty, but this code assert failed at line `assert(large_str.empty())`.

Did i misunderstand the semantics of `std::move`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Did i misunderstand the semantics of `std::move`?

Partly, yes. You forgot to cast the function parameter `str` to an rvalue. Within `some_method`, it has become an lvalue again. To fix this:

```
void some_method(std::string&& str) {
    my_str = std::move(str);
    //       ^^^^^^^^^ Necessary: invoke std::move a 2nd time
}
```

But do note the following. A "moved-from" `std::string` object is nothing you should `assert` on. From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), overload #8 (emphasis mine):

> Move constructor. Constructs the string with the contents of other using move semantics. other is left in valid, but **unspecified state**.

You don't want your program to depend on an unspecified state (even if it happens that a particular implementation makes `std::string::size` return 0 after the consumption of its resources).

Comment: *In practise*, all implementations will move the contents of a large string like this.  As such, this is a good mechanism for *test code* which is checking the move has occurred.  (The "unspecified state" is because many implementations with a short string optimization will copy the string if it is held locally.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Good point. But this is specific to `std::string`, or maybe the standard containers. What if you see assertions on "moved-from" objects often enough to adapt it as a habit for some codebase that you don't entirely know? Next step is to not `assert` some property, but use it for release builds, too... one could argue that "moved-from" objects should _never_ be touched as a matter of consistency-induced safety.

Comment: As a general rule, I agree.  For non-production code, particularly for this sort of test, I think it's OK.  (Also of course, for things like std::unique_ptr which *do* have defined contents after move.)